# UI Grid; Iterating Through Object

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I'm trying to iterate through my data.TeamMembers object in UI-Grid; i'm having trouble getting the data to show in my ui-grid.

I'm able to reference each array property by directly writing row.entity.teamMembers[0]..row.entity.teamMembers[1]....but i don't want to write every array property explicitly. row.entity.teamMembers.userProfile.firstName doesn't work as it's coming back as undefined.

How do I iterate through the object properties to get to the userProfile.firstName property?

Here is how the array looks:

```
teamMembers
:
Array(3)
0
:
{memberId: 4564, role: "", deleted: false, signatory: false, signatoryOrder: null, …}
1
:
{memberId: 4565, role: "", deleted: false, signatory: false, signatoryOrder: null, …}
2
:
{memberId: 4566, role: "", deleted: false, signatory: false, signatoryOrder: null, …}

:
current
:
false
deleted
:
false
enabled
:
1
memberId
:
4564
reportId
:
2936
reviewer
:
false
role
:
""
signatory
:
false
signatoryOrder
:
null
userProfile
:
contractor
:
false
email
:
"koryjcampbell@gmail.com"
firstName
:
"Kory"
id
:
null
lastName
:
"Campbell"
title
:
"Software Developer"
userAccountExists
:
false
userId
:
247
username
:
"koryjcampbell@gmail.com"






vm.teamGridOptions = {
    enableGridMenu: false,
    enableSorting: true,
    enableHorizontalScrollbar: 0, /*always hide horizontal scroll bar*/
    enableVerticalScrollbar: 1, /*always show vertical scroll bar*/
    rowHeight: 46,  
    columnDefs: [
            {
                    enableHiding: false,
                    enableColumnMenu: false,
                    displayName: 'First Name',
                    field: 'firstName',
                    cellClass: 'ui-grid-cell-contents',
                    cellTemplate: '<span>{{row.entity.teamMembers.userProfile.firstName}}</span>'

                },
```

]
}

Comment: You're sure that's what your 'array' looks like? Because if it *does* it doesn't seem to be an Array, and with that syntax I'm guessing it's *meant* to be an Object, but you seem to have missed some of it in your copy/paste.

Comment: it's an array of objects. the data is returning multiple properties, but i'm trying to refrence the teamMembers array in the data object

Comment: The team members array is a array of three objects, for reference